# Key blinding security in Ascon

Tags: keys, sponge

This [article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/796.pdf) explains the role of key blinding in Ascon. Key blinding in Ascon involves XORing the key with the capacity part after the permutation in both the initialization and finalization stages.

[image]

Quoting from the paper:

> we demonstrate that Ascon without key blinding (i.e., with only using
> the key to initialize the state) does not achieve authenticity under
> state recovery, but that the actual Ascon with key blinding achieves
> this unique property. The security bound is, logically, worse than
> that of plain authenticity, but is still reasonably high: authenticity
> under state recov- ery is achieved up to time complexity around
> min{2k/μ,2c/2}. We also argue tightness of the security result.

In simpler terms, how does key blinding enhance security?

Comment: It helps prevent key recovery/universal forgery when the internal state is recovered by an attacker (e.g. via side-channel attacks or significant nonce reuse). I'd recommend reading the [Ascon spec](https://ascon.iaik.tugraz.at/specification.html) as it's very readable as far as papers/specifications go. It's unfortunate most papers aren't so readable. A lot of papers on the sponge/duplex construction in particular seem to be unnecessarily complicated as if there's a prize for who can write the most confusing paper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.it is spot on.

Comment: @samuel-lucas6 Could you convert your comment into an answer? I think pointing out the relevant section of the paper would be enough reference and the answer seems clear to hadyrama...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [Ascon specification](https://ascon.iaik.tugraz.at/files/asconv12-nist.pdf), the keyed initialisation and finalisation help prevent key recovery/universal forgery when the internal state is recovered by an attacker during associated data/plaintext/ciphertext processing. For example, via side-channel attacks or significant nonce reuse.

The authors use the terms 'robust' and 'robustness' when discussing this, not to be confused with [other](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/793) [definitions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/288) of robustness. Alongside 'key blinding', people [have](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/1525) called it 'state-blinding' and 'output-blinding'.

Achieving this prevents [full-state absorption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/541), which would provide greater efficiency. However, a benefit of avoiding this and doing key blinding is [committing security](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/1525), a property lacking from most [current](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/526) and [new](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/1379) AEAD schemes, including [many](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/1525) NIST LWC finalists.

[NORX v3.0](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/round3/norxv30.pdf) from the [CAESAR competition](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/caesar-submissions.html) also does key blinding but outputs the whole capacity key blinded as the tag (128 or 256 bits). This helped protect against some [attacks](https://tosc.iacr.org/index.php/ToSC/article/view/589) on NORX v2.0.

[image: NORX v3.0 diagram]

However, to my knowledge, nobody has studied key blinding for larger tags (e.g. extending the tag size in Ascon, which has a smaller state than NORX). For instance, is it better to blind and output more of the capacity or do additional permutation calls? Probably the latter, but that complicates key blinding. The former is much simpler if you extend the key size (e.g. Ascon-80pq has a 160-bit key, so it could have a 160-bit tag).